# Jetpack Compose, how to change the color of the action of the snackbar in .showSnackbar() in a Scaffold?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-snackbar

So, I'm showing a snackbar inside of my Scaffold, using the `scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar()` method, though the colour of the "Undo" action is dark purple, and I would like to change it to something else.

I know that I can show it as a custom component, though I would like to launch it in a `coroutineScope()`, which I think is not possible.

My code is like this for the snackbar.

```
scope.launch {
  val result = scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
    message = "Note Deleted",
    actionLabel = "Undo",
  )
  if (result == SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed) { 
    viewModel.onEvent(NotesEvent.RestoreNote)
  }
}
```

I would like to know if it's possible to change the text colour of the action here and if yes, it would be cool if you could give an example or a resource.

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can customize your `Snackbar` using the **`actionColor`** parameter.

Something like:

```
val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
Scaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    snackbarHost = {
        // reuse default SnackbarHost to have default animation and timing handling
        SnackbarHost(it) { data ->
            // custom snackbar with the custom colors
            Snackbar(
                actionColor = Green,
                //contentColor = ...,
                snackbarData = data
            )
        }
    },
```

Then just use it:

```
scope.launch {
        scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
               message = "Note Deleted",
               actionLabel = "Undo"
         )
}
```

[image]

Comment: how can one change the color based on runtime cases? for eg Green for success, else red... as we created the host how to resend the value of the state to the host?

Comment: @tronku I guess you can just make a function that returns the colour and checks for that information.

Comment: Only changing the `backgroundColor` works for me. `actionColor` and `contentColor` stay like a light gray or partially transparent white. Any idea why?