# Jetpack compose snackbar action click is not working

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-snackbar

- I have displayed a snackbar with specific action in Jetpack compose but click listener on that action is not working.

Here is my code:

```
@Composable
fun MySnackBar() {
        Snackbar(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
            action = {
                TextButton(color = LightBlue,onClick = {
                  Log.d("TAG", "Action clicked!")
                }) {
                    Text(text = "Remove")
                }
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "This is a basic Snackbar with action item")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In a Scaffold you can use:

```
   val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
   scope.launch {

        val snackbarResult = scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
            message = "This is a basic Snackbar with action item",
            actionLabel = "Remove"
        )
        when (snackbarResult) {
            SnackbarResult.Dismissed -> {}
            SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed -> {}
        }
    }
```

[image]

If you don't have a `Scaffold` you can use something like:

```
        val snackState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
        SnackbarHost(hostState = snackState, Modifier){ data ->
            Snackbar(
                actionColor = Red,
                snackbarData = data
            )
        }
```

and then use the same code above to show the `Snackbar` changing `scaffoldState.snackbarHostState` to `snackState`.

Comment: I cannot use this implementation because I need custom color action button of snackbar !

Comment: @AndroidDev why not? Just check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69734835/jetpack-compose-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-action-of-the-snackbar-in-shows/69735183#69735183

Comment: Yes I have checked this link but due to usage of `Snackbarhost` at other place I cannot use this because I do not have scaffold present in current file. I am showing snackbar at the bottom of the screen using `Box` alignment property.

Comment: @AndroidDev Just updated the answer. The code is pretty the same.

Comment: Still action click listener is not working!

Comment: Did you implement `SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed -> {}`? Just tried, it works

Answer (score 0):

Button( onClick = { Snackbar(action = {}) { Text("hello") } }`

Comment: Snackbar is visible but it's action click is not working!!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).